# сохранить через cookie или LocalStorage для выбранного елемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Задача в том, чтобы при клике на кнопку, сохранять её id и применять её для элементов `nav__elem`, чтобы при нажатии например на `<button id="module-1">` применялся класс selected к этой кнопке, а также Добавлялся класс selected и к `<span class="nav__elem module-1">nav elem 1</span>` и чтобы при перезагрузке страницы изменения сохранились, но если кликнуть по активной кнопки то удалился selected класс с кнопки и nav__elem module-1. Не используя es6, может быть выбрано несколько элементов, не только один

```html
<div class="nav">
  <span class="nav__elem module-1">nav elem 1</span>
  <span class="nav__elem module-2">nav elem 2</span>
  <span class="nav__elem module-3">nav elem 3</span>
</div>
<div class="btns">
  <button id="module-1">elem 1</button>
  <button id="module-2">elem 2</button>
  <button id="module-3">elem 3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я решил эту проблему через localStorage:

```
function initModules() {
       if (localStorage.getItem('favModules')) {
            var favModules = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('favModules'));
            for (let i = 0; i < favModules.length; i++) {
                  $("#"+favModules[i]).addClass("selected");
                  $("."+favModules[i]).addClass("selected");
                }
        } else {
            return false;
        } 
    };
    initModules();

    function setModules() {
       var favModules = [];
        $("button").click(function () {
            if (!$(this).hasClass("selected")) {
                var elem = $(this).attr("id");
                $(this).addClass("selected");
                $("." + elem).addClass("selected");
            } else {
                var elem = $(this).attr("id");
                $(this).removeClass("selected");
                $("." + elem).removeClass("selected");
            }
            favModules = [];
            $("button.selected").each(function () {
                var self = $(this).attr("id");
                favModules.push(self);
            });

            window.localStorage.setItem('favModules', JSON.stringify(favModules));
        }); 
    };
    setModules();
```

Comment: Ну и намучился,  благодарю за вопрос...  Мне было интересно его решить))) Но решил не без помощи...

Answer (score 2):

Здесь пример не будет работать... 
Вопрос решил не без помощи коллег...

```js
let button = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
let module = document.getElementsByClassName("module");

var elem = [];
for (let i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    module[i].classList.toggle("selected");
    button[i].classList.toggle("selected");
    elem = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
      if (button[i].classList.contains("selected")) {
        elem.push(i);
      }
    }
    localStorage.setItem("elem", JSON.stringify(elem));
  });
}

window.onload = function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem("elem")) {
    var elemZ = localStorage.getItem("elem");
    var lsArr = JSON.parse(elemZ);
    for (let i = 0; i < lsArr.length; i++) {
      button[lsArr[i]].classList.add("selected");
      module[lsArr[i]].classList.add("selected");
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <span class="nav__elem module module-1">nav elem 1</span>
  <span class="nav__elem module module-2">nav elem 2</span>
  <span class="nav__elem module module-3">nav elem 3</span>
</div>
<div class="btns">
  <button class="button" id="module-1">elem 1</button>
  <button class="button" id="module-2">elem 2</button>
  <button class="button" id="module-3">elem 3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: можно без es6 пожалуйста показать как сделать нужно

Comment: Минутку...  щас покажу...

Comment: спасибо работает отлично, у меня только вопрос, тут можно чтобы было выбрано несколько элементов, не только один, можно и больше, я пытаюсь поправить ваш код но чтото не выходит

Comment: Dima Vleskov, объясни толком..какие элем?

Comment: можно чтобы было не только например elem 1(nav elem1), выбран, а можно несколько выбрать elem1(nav elem1), elem2(nav elem2)... а щас только один елемент может быть активный

Comment: погоди я тебе все распишу в коментариях

Comment: Надеюсь внятно объяснил...

Comment: Dima Vleskov, я привет, я понял  о чем ты, но вот с утра пытаюсь, не получается решить вопрос с `localstorage`, для нескольких элементов...  Убери галочку...  я то я не могу ответ удалить, он не верный и на твой вопрос не отвечает...   Я изначально тебя не понял о том, что тебе надо... На счет нескольких элем классом  `selected`